# Career Development plan for university position

Tags: university, job, faculty-application

Certain academic job ads at the university request a Career Development Plan document. I have never heard about this. What should a document like this contain?

Comment: This is not an academic custom.  It's a corporate custom.

Comment: I think to answer this we need to know what other documents you are submitting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typical elements might be research directions, course development, grant writing ideas and such. Professional society membership and activity can also be important in some places.

Note that most universities have a three part expectation of faculty; research, teaching, service. Different universities have different ideas about the relative importance of each. Some will strongly favor research and others teaching. But the faculty expectation is normally closely aligned with what that university sees as its mission, which is normally multi-faceted.

Keep that in mind as you try to develop a plan for your "development".

---

Note that in my annual faculty evaluation (by the dean) I was always expected to give a plan for the coming year and my previous year plan was always discussed as to fulfillment. It had an impact on salary increments, mostly, but for those who don't produce much it can have other consequences. I think this may be fairly common.

But the advantage of such a system for faculty is that you can, with the dean's consent, pretty much define your own path.